# Array parameter with dimension

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof

How come even if I'm giving full dimensions, the size of the array is just one of a pointer? Is this decaying too?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void function(char* arr[1][2]){
    cout << sizeof(arr); // 4
}

int main() {
    char* params2d[1][2] = { {"hello", "world"} };
    cout << sizeof(params2d); // 8
    function(params2d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is the way it is. `int n[42]` is the same as `int n[]` and `int* n` when they are function parameters. And array arguments decay to pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the function declarations

```
void function(char* arr[1][2]);
void function(char* arr[][2]);
void function(char* (*arr)[2]);
```

are same. In case of multidimensional arrays, first dimension can be omitted.  So, whether you write

```
void function(char* arr[1][2]);
```

or

```
void function(char* arr[10][2]);
```

compiler convert it to

```
void function(char* (*arr)[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's decaying. A function parameter of type "array of `X`" is just syntactic sugar for "pointer to `X`." Unless a parameter's type is "reference to array," an array used as argument for that parameter is *always* converted to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the array by reference, you should use:

```
void function(char* (&arr)[1][2])
```

Currently your declaration is similar to:

```
void function(char* (*arr)[2]);
```

Comment: This is not answering the question.